# Speculative: What would happen if towers with supermagnets would be built around an experimental tokamak?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, fusion

It is a speculative question from an amateur. I am interested in an expert reply carved-out for a non-expert

As I'm avidly observing [ITER](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITER) developments and I'm a great fan of the project (as a child I was dreaming of fusion-powered city-states), I wonder what would happen "if" reinforced towers, would be built around the [tokamak](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak)  creating an extra super-field around it. How would it interact with the plasma generated by the tokamak, and how would it reinforce the axial magnetic field in the Tokamak itself and with what consequences for the cycle?. Is there any possibility that it might reinforce the fusion process and its sustenance? Avoiding all the engineering details and difficulties, please use this question to explore ideas and possibilities, I would be extremely grateful for informed answers,

Thank you,
Kind Regards,
Non-physicist.

Comment: Off topic:  I'm no expert, but the concept of enormous power generation stations seems like an enormous security risk. Sabotage or one big bomb and ...  There are proposals for small, distributed fusion power generating stations that seem less of a security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only field of use in this context would be *magnetic*. Since the strength of the magnetic field falls off like 1/(radius)^3, putting the magnetic field generators (which would be coils of wire that were carrying current) far away from the tokamak would have almost no effect on its operation.

Tokamaks already have magnetic fields in their design to help confine the plasma inside them, and the coils that create those fields are positioned as close to the plasma chamber as physically possible.